# Upgraded to AndroidStudio v.4.0 now compile error

Tags: android-studio

As the title says I have upgraded to AndroidStudio v4.0 and now my project will not compile. I had errors and moved all my java files to the 'gen' folder and then project would show without errors.

I have set compiler to ECLIPSE.

Now I get this error:

> Error:Module 'AndroidstudioProjects' production:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/android/resources/ResourceFolderType

Comment: Your sources should live in `src/main/java`, not `gen`. Also, you shouldn't really be doing anything with Eclipse for Android development in 2020.